# Compute the max within a report

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to compute the `max{}` within a report statement in `netlogo`.

I currently have the following expression:

```
report bestBid + (max{cost, bestAsk}- bestBid)/n
```

I intend to report a bid to a procedure requiring a bid to be submitted.

Answer (score 1):

`max` only works on lists, so you need to put the values in a list:

```
max list cost bestAsk
```

you might decide it reads a bit better with parentheses:

```
max (list cost bestAsk)
```

Comment: Thank you Seth, it actually makes a lot of sense. I presume I can use the same thought when dealing with min?